# Theory number problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to prove that there are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ for which $2n^2+3$ and $n^2+n+1$ are relatively prime.

This is not true for every $n$ (for example, $n=4$), I tried to check for odd $n$ but can't find way to prove it (I tried induction). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any common divisor of $2n^2+3$ and $n^2+n+1$ divides $2(n^2+n+1)-(2n^2+3)$, which is $2n-1$.

Any common divisor of $2n^2+3$ and $2n-1$ divides $2n^2+3-n(2n-1)$, which is $n+3$.

And any common divisor of $2n-1$ and $n+3$ divides $7$.

Now produce infinitely many numbers $2n^2+3$ that are not divisible by $7$.

**Remark:** We have in essence used the Euclidean Algorithm for polynomials. If we chase down details, we find that the gcd is $1$ except when $n\equiv 4\pmod{7}$.

Comment: Wonderful!Can you explain me how you used Euclidean Algorithm in this steps?

Comment: When we try to find the gcd of two numbers, we divide and find the remainder. I was actually using the Euclidean Algorithm for polynomials.